# basic c pointer returning

Tags: c++, pointers

The following app crashes with nullpointer. I am wondering whats wrong...

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

char* getFileData(char* fileName);
bool createShader( int shaderType, const char* shader, const char* shaderFile ) ;
void glShaderSource(int shader, int count, const char** string, const int* length);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* shader = getFileData("filea.csd");
    bool success = createShader(1, shader, "filea.csd");
    return 0;
}

char* getFileData(char* fileName) {
    if(!strcmp(fileName, "filea.csd"))
        return "this is the content of the file a\0";
    else if(!strcmp(fileName, "fileb.csd"))
        return "this is the content of the file b\0";
    else if(!strcmp(fileName, "filec.csd"))
        return "this is the content of the file c\0";
    else 
        return "";
}

bool createShader( int shaderType, const char* shader, const char* shaderFile ) 
{
    int shaderHandle = 122;

    glShaderSource( shaderHandle, 1, &shader, NULL ); ////This line is where it crashes.
    return true;
}

void glShaderSource(int shader, int count, const char** string, const int* length) {
}
```

Comment: you don't call `getFileData(...)` at all. Post more code

Comment: The code you've posted above doesn't compile; you're missing closing parentheses from your calls.  Please post the real code that you're actually compiling; the above code is correct except for the missing parentheses.

Comment: @ColeJohnson `getFileData` is called in `strdup`

Comment: After adding the missing parens, I get no errors... http://codepad.org/qc19lQ4a

Comment: To follow up on templatetypedef's comment, you don't need to post the real code (which will have too many extraneous parts), you need to post a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/). Note that string literals should be treated as `const char *`.

Comment: when I use shader variable in main I get null pointer error. Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: What is the compiler that you are using ? I tried with GCC, but no error !

Comment: I am running it in vc++ WIN32.

Comment: Well I tried this and it runs without segfaulting. Post the code that fails instead of the code that works.

Comment: I've just edited the code to make it look excatly how am using.

Comment: getFileData is not returning NULL it seems to be working but &shader in function createShader is where it fails.

Comment: In the actual program, I am using multi line string 
return "file content line one"
       "file content line two"
       "file content line three\0";

Comment: @codetiger You have to post compilable sample program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel I just edited to code to a simple compiled code. This code gives same problem during runtime.

Comment: Verify that at each level, you do not have a null pointer.  Pass in byref(&) to that function if you do, and fix the rest.

Comment: This starts to look more and more like a difference between headers and library

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat] when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Pointer is NULL, try passing the double pointer.  Something of the form

```
bool createShader( GLenum shaderType, const char** shader, const char* shaderFile )//<-- change 
{
    GLuint shaderHandle = glCreateShader( shaderType );

    glShaderSource( shaderHandle, 1, shader, NULL ); //<--change
    glCompileShader( shaderHandle );

    int status = 0;

    glGetShaderiv( shaderHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
}

void main () {
      char* shader = strdup(getFileData("filea.csd"));
      bool success = createShader(shaderType, &shader, "filea.csd"); //<--change
      delete shader;
      return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think checking the return value from glCreateShader might be a good thing. Make sure it's non-zero.

The line

`delete shader`

is also wrong. It may not be crashing there but you need to use `free` to release memory allocated by malloc.

Comment: I tried free, but the code crashes before doing the delete within the function createShader

Answer (score 0):

One bug I see is this line:

```
    delete shader;
```

That line will only work correctly if the memory pointed by shader was allocated with the new operator.  But if we look at your getFileData() method, we see that the character arrays it returns are not allocated by new, but rather are static data.

So the fix would be to have getFileData() return a character array that was allocated by the new operator, or better yet a std::string.  Using dynamically-allocated character arrays for string handling is very error prone and not recommended.